# How can I make this code thread safe?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Just learning aspects of Ruby multithreading in this simple exercise... I'm certain I'm missing something obvious, please and thank you in advance... I've been told my code here will cause problems when run across multiple threads.  Why and how to fix?  Thank you!

```
MAX_MESSAGES = 100
messageCounter = 0

def process_message(msg)
  if( msg.valid?  && message_counter < MAX_MESSAGES )
    msg.file
    message_counter += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: This code does not provide enough information to demonstrate thread-safety bugs, but what I can tell you is if you are mutating `message_counter` across multiple threads you will definitely get a weird behavior

Comment: If a thread switch occurs between `message_counter < MAX_MESSAGES` and `message_counter += 1`, you could end up with a `message_counter` value of `101` (or more, depending on the number of threads).

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, `message_counter += 1` would be problematic for multithreading because it translates to `message_counter = message_counter + 1`. The problem is that this has to do two things: get the value of `message_counter` and increment it, then store the result in `message_counter`.

Imagine two threads doing this in parallel: they both get a value of 0, they both increment it to 1, then they both store a value of 1. So `message_counter` is 1 even though two messages were processed.

However in Ruby, depending on the interpreter you are using, `message_counter += 1` may or may not be protected by the GVL, so you might not actually see any weird behavior if you throw this method in a bunch of threads. The GVL makes sure that the VM doesn't enter an invalid state due to multiple threads trying to access the same Ruby objects at once. So in GVL-protected interpreters (which includes the official one) you can generally throw any old Ruby code in some threads and everything will work fine.

**However**, the GVL does **not** attempt to protect resources *outside of the VM*. So if you have multiple threads all trying to print to one log file, or use one database connection, or read from one socket, all hell can break lose. In those cases you need to use a [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Thread/Mutex.html) to protect the shared resource from concurrent access. Using a mutex is still a good idea even if you think the GVL might protect you; at worst it will cause a slight overhead when you lock/unlock it.

Comment: The GIL will not protect you in this case, you can write a script and experiment with it

Comment: I did. I couldn't manage to get the threads to cause a miscount.

Comment: @bjhaid It depends on the operation being performed. That example involves two separate method calls, so it is possible for the threads to interleave in a way that causes problems. From my tests it looks like `+=` is a single call protected by the GVL so it is not possible for threads to interfere. But note that my answer says this behavior should not be relied on.